# Swift: creating quarter circle with SKCropNode not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uibezierpath

The code below fails to generate a quarter circle. However, if you change the end angle to .pi, the code generates a semi-circle as expected.

Why does it fail for quarter circles?

```
    // Create circle
    let circleSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    let circle = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Dot.png"), color: color, size: circleSize)
    circle.colorBlendFactor = 1.0

    // Add circle to crop node
    let cropNode = SKCropNode()
    cropNode.addChild(circle)

    // Set crop node mask
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: width/2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi/2, clockwise: true)
    let maskNode = SKShapeNode(path: bezierPath.cgPath)
    maskNode.isAntialiased = false
    maskNode.lineWidth = 0
    maskNode.fillColor = color
    cropNode.maskNode = maskNode
```

**Dot.png (image is white so click below to download):**

[image: Dot.png below (white circle so click on space below)]

Comment: what if you switch the startAngle and endAngle values? Or change clockwise to `false`?

Comment: @vacawama changing clockwise to false does not fix it, will try swapping angles.

Comment: @vacawama swapping angles also did not fix it. does this code work for you?

Comment: The line `let circle = SKSpriteNode(texture: "Circle.png", color: color, size: circleSize)` gives me **Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'SKTexture?'**

Comment: @vacawama sorry redacted code last minute, updated question with the line that compiles (but requires a circle image on your side)

Comment: @vacawama also uploaded the circle image you will need, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are only drawing the arc, and the `UIBezierPath` closes the path by drawing a line back to the start.  When you draw a semicircle, that works because the line drawn is the diameter of the circle.

In the case of a quarter circle, you end up with a chord that connects the two endpoints, but that doesn't give you the desired result.

To fix this, draw a line to the center of the circle `(0, 0)` after you draw the arc.  Then when the path is closed, it will draw the other radius back to the starting point of the arc.

**New bezierPath code:**

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: width/2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi/2, clockwise: true)
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked well! Do you ever do any consulting BTW?

Comment: No, I have a day job and do SO for fun.